# Energy needed to spin a flywheel under special circumstances.

Tags: abstract-algebra

first thing, sorry but the tags used here are beyond my knowledge. I believe my title is descriptive enough. If not perhaps a forum user could recommend tags.
I have designed and 3D printed a drive that outputs to 1~4 flywheels. I now find myself needing information I’m not qualified to produce. I need someone who can answer how much energy, converted to watts if possible, is used to spin a flywheel or multiples of the same flywheel at given speeds. I have a feeling this may be a mundane question mathematically, I can only hope its context adds interest. If it can be answered here is the (I hope not too detailed) information.

Each flywheel is printed from a 3M polymer and is basically just a frame to hold the weights. the weights consist of steel nuts and bolts. The nuts and bolts are arranged into a ring around the perimeter of the printed flywheel.

Flywheel diameter               151.545mm
                thickness                       12mm
                weight                           40 grams
                shaft diameter               12mm

Weight ring outside diameter   149.381mm
                    inside diameter     111.401mm
                    thickness                     33.5mm
                    weight                       1242 grams

The flywheels are set in pairs with each pair independently powered by the drive but the pairs are also connected to each other with linkage bars. I know thats crazy but it’s a pretty novel design when the drive is factored in. Flywheel(s) is spun up to the maximum speed allowed by this build scale. To slow the flywheels, friction is applied to the outer surface of only one of the flywheels thus slowing any others. The specific questions I need answers to are;

How many watts are needed to spin 1~4 flywheels at 214rpm with no load applied?
How many watts are needed to spin 1~4 flywheels at 143rpm or 60rpm, slowed from 214rpm by friction on one flywheel only?

Not sure if it is needed but 0 to 214rpm is 4 seconds.

Because of the unique design of this drive Im not able to measure how many watts it is using. I know how many I am feeding it, just don’t have any way to measure how much of it is being used. Hope you find pity on me cause Im going goofy trying to figure this out.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: If you know the moment of inertia of a flywheel about its axis - call it $I$, then if it spins at $\omega$ radians per second, its kinetic energy is $\frac 12I\omega^2$ joules

Comment: Thanks David Quinn. I guess I should have said in words what I intimated in the OP. I have NO math skills beyond an elementary school level. Though your answer is greatly appreciated it is Sanskrit to me. Sorry.

Comment: The abstract algebra tag is inappropriate, and you might have more luck asking on the physics stack exchange site.

Comment: Thanks again David. This is all so far beyond my intellect. The device I have developed is actually quite unique and has capabilities beyond any other drive/output in existence. As I live in Tampa Fl. I think I may just take it to USF research park and see if they can help me.